# What is: for i in `ls ${ILPM_APPLICATION_LOG_DIR}/${PREFIX}*`

Tags: bash

```
APPLICATION_LOG_DIR=/home/users/sosst51/test-chinboon/logs/testdata1
PREFIX=mylog

for i in `ls ${APPLICATION_LOG_DIR}/${PREFIX}*`
```

Is this a `for loop` whereby i am passing the `ls` of the directory into `i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, `for s in string` will take a string and split it on whitespace, and iterate over each of the words. So:

```
for s in a b c; do echo $s; done
```

would print:

```
a
b
c
```

By passing it the output of ls, you're iterating over all of the files in that directory (careful though, it's going to break if any of the filenames contain spaces). This one in particular is iterating over files that start with "mylog".

Comment: good answer. just for posterity, the string is split on characters in `$IFS` which is whitespace by default.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a `for` loop.  Yes, the output of the `ls` command is used to provide the list of values  that `$i` takes.

The output of the `ls` command is split into separate words at the white space (such as newlines, or blanks or tabs).  This means that if any filenames contain white space, the names will be split into two (or more) components.